# Exclusively using direct DOM manipulation in React for style injections into the head. Is there anything inherently wrong with this?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I know direct DOM manipulation should be avoided at all costs in React, and normally I wouldn't even think of using it. I've recently been working on some component packages for use within my company. All of our projects utilize different CSS solutions, so I need to come up with a singular method for handling shared components.

I'd prefer not to have dozens of `import '../..css'` statements for every separate component package, and don't want to bundle all the components/css into one lib because some of these won't be used in specific projects. So as far as I can tell, the alternatives are to either use a CSS-in-JS library and add it as a dependency, use inline styles (`style={{}}`), or just use `<style>` tags in the body.

I know the last two aren't really encouraged, and I'd prefer to avoid adding another dep if possible. So, I started looking into how these CSS-in-JS libraries for React go about getting the stylesheets in the `<head>` of the document.

Turns out, every CSS-in-JS library I checked is just using direct DOM manipulation, i.e. `document.querySelector('head')?.innerHTML += '<style>...</style>'` with cleanup in the `useEffect` return, which makes alot of sense, I don't know why I assumed they were accomplishing style injections in a more 'React' way. I'm used to NextJS and `next/head` and sometimes forget that vanilla React doesn't really provide you with a way to update the `<head>`.

I have been considering just handling styles the direct way, but something about this just feels off to me. From everything I know, direct DOM manipulation and React should not be utilized together. But at the same time, this seems to be a specific scenario where it is alright to use it, especially considering these CSS-in-JS libraries are reliably doing so.

So, should doing this be avoided at all costs? Or is this one of the few situations where it is acceptable and makes sense?